# How to determine if a simple product is a variant of a master configurable product?

Tags: magento2

So let say I have a master configurable product that has many variant products under it. So if I understand it correctly, each of those variant products is a Simple Product type right? My question is how do I check if a Simple Product (given its ID) is a variant product that belong to a master configurable product programmatically?

Comment: You want to get the configurable product Id based on the assigned associated product or say child product right ?
based on that you can add the check

Comment: @RahulSingh, I want to check if a simple product is a variant (or child ?) product of any product. The objective is I want to set its visibility to invisible (in search & catalog) if it is a variant product given only its ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private $configurableProductType;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable $configurableProductType
) {
    ...
    $this->configurableProductType = $configurableProductType;
}

.....

$id = '5'; // Your simple product id
$product = $this->configurableProductType->getParentIdsByChild($id);
if ($product) {
    echo "It is a child of configurable product";
} else {
    echo "It is not a child of configurable product";
}
```

Comment: Happy Learning :)

Comment: Dinesh Yadav is right but I suggest to use model \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::getParentIdsByChild instead of resource model \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable::getParentIdsByChild not to miss some plugins for getParentIdsByChild method.